# How to setup virtual environment to run tensorflow benchmarks

Tags: python, tensorflow, benchmarking

My purpose is setting up virtual environment to run [tensorflow benchmark](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks) but I am getting an error at last statement after running following code. May I ask what I should do to resolve this issue? FYI: I am using Python 3.6.7 with only pip and virtualenv packages and CUDA 9.2/cuDNN7 installed (all dlls in system path).

```
virtualenv venv
venv\scripts\activate
#now you should be in virtual environment
#install using pip
pip install tf-nightly-gpu

python
import tensorflow
```

Error message:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\MyWork\testarea\testvirtualenv\venv\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer just after writing the question.

Downgrading CUDA 9.2 to 9.0 before copying cudnn64_7.dll (cuDNN 7.3.1 for CUDA 9.0) to CUDA bin directory made it work.

In the end, following script produced two different results from two different machines.

```
virtualenv venv
venv\scripts\activate
pip install tf-nightly-gpu    
python tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --num_gpus=1 --batch_size=32 --model=resnet50 --variable_update=parameter_server
```

**7th gen quad-core i7 with GTX 970**

total images/sec: 78.16

**AMD 1920X with GTX 1080**

total images/sec: 147.77